# Rails Testing ArgumentError: When assigning attributes, you must pass a hash as an argument.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, integration-testing

There is something wrong with my Rails testing setup. Right now, when I have data in my fixture, Rails does not recognize it as a hash.

```
require 'test_helper'

class TravelerTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase

  def setup
    @traveler = Traveler.new(:one)
  end
```

This is where I am getting the following error: 
"ArgumentError: When assigning attributes, you must pass a hash as an argument.
    test/models/traveler_test.rb:6:in `setup'"

My traveler.yml looks like this:

```
one:
  firstname: John
  lastname: Smith
  email: example@email.com
  encrypted_password: '123456'
  confirmed_at: 2016-01-02 08:31:23
  confirmation_sent_at: 2016-01-02 08:30:59

two: {}
# column: value
```

Comment: RSpec guy here but wouldn't you say `travelers(:one)` rather than trying to instantiate a new `Traveler` instance via the model class?

Comment: That did the trick it looks like. Thanks!